# How to compile VASP without the flags -DNGXhalf and -DNGZhalf?

Tags: vasp, software-assistance, spin-orbit-coupling

I'm trying to do spin-orbit coupling calculations with VASP but when I started to run them, I got this error:

```
ERROR: non collinear calculations require that VASP is compiled
  without the flag -DNGXhalf and -DNGZhalf
```

So how may I compile VASP without those flags?

Comment: Have you seen the vasp_ncl in your software directory?

Comment: Which OS and which compiler are you using to compile VASP? Or are you using a precompiled binary? If that's the case, you have to either find a version which is compiled without those flags, or compile your own.

Comment: +1 But have you had a chance to consider the comments by Jack and S R Maiti? If the asker doesn't interact with the question then it can get closed for being "abandoned". If you figured out a solution to the problem, we'd really appreciate if you can write an answer here so that it can help future users!

Comment: OS : ubuntu 18.04 , compiler :ifort 2020

Comment: yes there is vasp_ncl in my software directory

Comment: @SRMaiti were the OP's comments after this question's closure, enough for you to answer the question? If so, we can re-open the question.